# html2canvas with browserify doesn't work

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify, html2canvas

I tested the html2canvas as a regular script and it seemed to be working fine. Now I thought to use the npm-package and it just seems very uncooperative. By another words, it won't do a thing, or never fires the `then`-function.

The Installed package: v0.5.0-alpha2

Any ideas what to do?

```js
var html2canvas = require('html2canvas');
html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
    debugger;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var html2canvas = require('html2canvas');
 window.html2canvas = html2canvas;
 html2canvas(document.body)
 .then(function(canvas) {
   debugger;
 });
```